# refresh div in php based on the ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am creating a php application. In that when user change the value of a date picker he will be ask for confirmation. If he confirms, the date in the field with id expiry and archive_expiry will be changed. Now I am getting the correct json response for this two fields from the controller and the value in the expiry field is changing. But the second field is showing the updated value only once. All other times the changes occurred in the db is getting as the correct response when I alert it but the archive_expiry div is not refreshing with the correct value. The code I am using is given below

```html
<div class="controls input-append date form_date " data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy/mm/dd">
  <span class="add-on"><?php echo $this->Form->input('expiry', array('size' => 12, 'type' => 'text', 'id' => 'expiry', 'onchange' => 'confirmChange()', 'value' => __(date("Y/m/d", strtotime($project['expiry']))), 'readonly' => true, 'style' => 'border:1px solid #fff', 'label' => false)) ?></span>
  <span class="add-on" style="background-color:#eeeeee; border:1px solid #ccc;"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
  <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input2" value="" />
</div>

<div id="archiveExpiry">
  <?php echo (date("Y/m/d", strtotime($project['archive_expiry']) )) ?>
</div>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  var a = '<?php echo (!empty($project['
  expiry '])) ? date("Y/m/d",    strtotime($project['
  expiry '])) : null; ?>';

  function confirmChange() {
    var r = confirm("公開期限を更新しますか？");
    if (r === true) {
      changeDeliveryDeadLine();
    } else {
      document.getElementById("expiry").value = a;
    }
  }
</script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  function changeDeliveryDeadLine() {
    var expiry = $('#dtp_input2').val();
    if (expiry !== '') {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo $this->Url->build(['action' => 'changeDeliveyDeadLine']) ?>',
        data: {
          'expiry': expiry,
          'projectId': '<?php echo (!empty($project['id'])) ? $project['id '] : null; ?>'
        },
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(out) {
          a = out.result;
          b = out.archive;
          document.getElementById("expiry").value = a;
          $('#archiveExpiry').replaceWith(b);
        }
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Why the second div(archive_expiry) is not refreshing with the updated value.

Comment: use `document.getElementById("archive_expiry").innerHTML = a;` to get updated value

Comment: Thanks @Deep3015 it is working correctly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use .html() in this case:

```
$('#archiveExpiry').html(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong quotes for `var a =` , `url:` and `'projectId'`

Use `"` double quotes if using `'` single quotes inside and use escape `"\""`  if double quotes inside double quotes.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

when I replaced the code

```
success: function(out) {
      a = out.result;
      b = out.archive;
      document.getElementById("expiry").value = a;
      $('#archiveExpiry').replaceWith(b);
    }
```

with the code

```
 a = out.result;
      b = out.archive;         
      document.getElementById("expiry").value = a; 
      document.getElementById("archiveExpiry").innerHTML = b;
```

solves the issue